# column width expands page after using landscape, minipage & twocolumn

Tags: two-column, landscape, width

I am writing a two column report: portrait oriented page. For certain pages I used landscape orientation. In this page a figure takes whole width of the page (29cm).  Under this figure I put a two column text.  The next page should be normal portrait format and two columns but the columns are as wide as in the landscape page which is much wider than the columns in the portrait page and the columns expands the page.  How can I set the column widths back to the normal width: portrait columns instead of landscape columns?

In codes:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,subfigure,amsmath,hyperref,float,url,multirow,color,
    colortbl,lastpage,totcount,rotating,pdflscape,tabularx,eurosym}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}%between columns
    \graphicspath{{./fig/}}\regtotcounter{page}

    \pagestyle{fancy}%header
    \setlength\headsep{0.5cm}\setlength\topskip{0cm}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}

    \begin{document}
    \title{something}\author{someone}
    %\pagestyle{empty} %No headings for the first pages.
    \headheight=14.5pt%\maketitle
    \lhead{\scriptsize\textit{\leftmark: \rightmark}}
\rhead{\scriptsize\textit{ \thepage/\total{page}}}
    \lfoot{\scriptsize\textit{\today}}
\cfoot{\scriptsize\textit{\copyright society}}
\rfoot{\scriptsize \textit{My Report}}
    %\begin{Indent}{1.7cm}\begin{IndentR}{1.7cm}%1column
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.6cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
    \newcommand{\chapter}[1]{\section{#1}}%report=>article

    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  

        \begin{landscape}
 here comes the figure width 27cm
        \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \twocolumn 
    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text
\end{minipage}                                                                  
        \end{landscape}

        %Next page should have normal portrait
% columns instead of landscape columns but it is not.

        \section{Bla Bla bla bla}

        Bla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla blaBla 
bla blaBla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla bla
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example into a _complete_ document so people can reproduce the problem. (also replace the `\incledegraphics` with text to remove dependency on external files.  Standard latex `\twocolumn` doesn't work in a minipage, which may be the cause of your problem, but hard to tell from this fragment.

Comment: Thanks. I could not see that \twocolumn did not work in minipage because it only works for the first column.  If my text is long enough it exceeds the bottom of the page instead of going to the second column.  And column widths of the next portrait oriented pages are destroyed.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File `OwnCommands.sty' not found.` I'm assuming this isn't needed for this example

Comment: It's an undocumented feature that `lscape` and `\twocolumn` do not mix. Also as noted earlier you can not use `\twocolumn` in a minipage.  instead of using `lscape` I would make up a minipage of the correct (landscape) size using `multicolumn` package (which does allow columsn in a minipage) and the rotate teh box using `\rotatebox`.

Comment: I inserted the multicol package.  I changed the code in: \rotatebox{90}{Figure Figure Figure \begin{minipage}\twocolumn text text text text\end{minipage}} But latex cannot rotate the page to landscape.

Comment: you would need \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}.....\end{minipage}}  ie just rotate a single minipage and as I have said multiple times you can not use `\twocolumn` inside a box. Use `\begin{multicols}`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You can to use `\rotatebox` and `multicols` rather than `landscape` and `\twocolumn`.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,subfigure,amsmath,hyperref,float,url,multirow,color,
    colortbl,lastpage,totcount,rotating,pdflscape,tabularx,eurosym,multicol}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}%between columns
    \graphicspath{{./fig/}}\regtotcounter{page}

    \pagestyle{fancy}%header
    \setlength\headsep{0.5cm}\setlength\topskip{0cm}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}

    \begin{document}
    \title{something}\author{someone}
    %\pagestyle{empty} %No headings for the first pages.
    \headheight=14.5pt%\maketitle
    \lhead{\scriptsize\textit{\leftmark: \rightmark}}
\rhead{\scriptsize\textit{ \thepage/\total{page}}}
    \lfoot{\scriptsize\textit{\today}}
\cfoot{\scriptsize\textit{\copyright society}}
\rfoot{\scriptsize \textit{My Report}}
    %\begin{Indent}{1.7cm}\begin{IndentR}{1.7cm}%1column
    \setlength{\parindent}{0.6cm} \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
    \newcommand{\chapter}[1]{\section{#1}}%report=>article

    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  
    Portrait oriented two column text  

\clearpage
\onecolumn
\noindent\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
    Landscape oriented two column text    Landscape oriented two column text
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\clearpage
\twocolumn

        %Next page should have normal portrait
% columns instead of landscape columns but it is not.

        \section{Bla Bla bla bla}

        Bla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla blaBla 
bla blaBla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla bla
      \end{document}
```